# What does 'text badly centered' mean, and what is its modern PGF/TikZ equivalent

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have inherited an old LaTeX document that uses old `\tikzstyle` way of defining styles.  Among other definitions there is one that reads

```
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20,
  text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=2cm, inner sep=0pt]
```

What does "text badly centered" mean, and what is its modern equivalent using

```
\tikzset{decision/.style={diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, ...}}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will find the explanations in manual 1.18 of TikZ which is available for [download here](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) (until when?) on page 122. 
Here is a screenshot of the explanation:

[image: screenshot]

And its copy:

> **text badly centered** centers the text, without balancing the lines.

The low-level code which is executed for the alignment is similar to

```
\parfillskip=0pt
\rightskip=0pt plus 1fil
\leftskip=0pt plus 1fil
```

---

#### The modern equivalent is **align=flush center**

[image: screenshot-2]

> **align=flush center** Works like **flush left** or **flush right**, only for center alignment. Because of all the trouble that results from the
>   **center** option in conjunction with narrow lines, I suggest picking this
>   option rather than center unless you have longer text, in which case
>   **center** will give the typographically better results.

The low-level code which is executed for the alignment is similar to

```
\parfillskip=0pt
\rightskip=0pt plus 2em
\leftskip=0pt plus 2em
\spaceskip=.3333em
\xspaceskip=.5em
```

Comment: I edited your answer with some low-level details.  Feel free to roll back.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you for adding these details. :-)